# Is it possible to force the app from going into power save mode?

Tags: android

How to force the app from going into power save mode in Android?

Comment: Do you _want_ every user of your app hunting you down and trying to kill you because you're destroying their battery? :-)

Comment: :) I want my app to not enter sleep mode

Comment: getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON); it works

Answer (score 2):

You want a wake lock. See:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html

Comment: Google and the Android documentation certainly are a powerful combination.  If only more people were aware of this before starting to program.

Comment: They only help if you know what to look for. 'Wake lock' is not an obvious term for this. Many's the time I have spent days trying to figure out how to solve a problem when simply knowing one keyword would have let me find everyone else's solution.